# Replace $markers$ in text file before Git commit

Tags: git, git-svn

I my text files (java) I use markers like `$Author$`, `$Date$`, `$Revision$` which are updated on each commit.

How can I do this in Git?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using Git's [smudge and clean filters](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html#Keyword-Expansion).
You can also do it using [pre-commit hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), but be [careful](http://codeinthehole.com/writing/tips-for-using-a-git-pre-commit-hook/).

Comment: Thanks, the "Keyword Expansion" section in the clean-filter link is what I needed.